# How to run awk in vim to get the longest line and its order number?

Tags: vim, awk

We can get the length of the longest line and order number  with command:

```
 awk '{ print length(), NR, $0 | "sort -rn" }' /tmp/test.txt |head -n 1
```

Now ,to open /tmp/test.txt with command vim.

```
:!awk '{ print length(), NR, $0 | "sort -rn" }' % |head -n 1

Press ENTER or type command to continue
head: cannot open ‘n’ for reading: No such file or directory
head: cannot open ‘1’ for reading: No such file or directory
sort: fflush failed: standard output: Broken pipe
sort: write error
```

How to fix it?

Comment: I cannot reproduce it. Please try it with `vim -u NONE /tmp/test.txt`; if that fixes it, do a binary search debug on your plugins. If it doesn't fix it, it may have to do with your OS or Vim version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command is quite inefficient. If you are using `awk` anyway, you should also let it calculate the length of the longest line:

```
 awk '{ l = length($0); a = (a > l) ? a : l } END {print a}' test.txt
```